# React array not updating properly

Tags: reactjs

I am experiencing a very weird bug in a basically fresh react project. I am attempting to update an array whenever the browser receives a keypress event. For some reason the update that I would expect to work is only editing the last value of the array or keeping it at a fixed length of 1.

```js
function Component() {
  const [keypresses, setKeypresses] = useState([]);
  
  function updateKeypresses(e) {
   setKeypresses([...keypresses, e.keyCode]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListeneder('keydown', updateKeypresses);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', updateKeypresses); 
    }  
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(keypresses);
  }, [keypresses])
}
```

```bash
Output: I dont have codes memorized so image nums

press a
~> [a]
press b
~> [b]
press c
~> [c]

What I would expect:
~> [a]
~> [a,b]
~> [a,b,c]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `updateKeypresses` is created on each render and always have latest version of `keypresses`. However, your effect in run only after first render, and it 'snapshots' version of `updateKeypresses` available on first render.  At this moment `keypresses` is empty, and every time event is triggered, your code effectively executes:

```
setKeypresses([...[], e.keyCode]);
```

To fix this you can either memoize function and put it into effect dependencies:

```
const [keypresses, setKeypresses] = useState([]);
  
const updateKeypresses = useCallback((e) => {
 setKeypresses([...keypresses, e.keyCode]);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListeneder('keydown', updateKeypresses);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', updateKeypresses); 
  }  
}, [updateKeypresses]);
```

Or, a bit simpler way it to use function with `setKeypresses`:

```
setKeypresses((prevKeypresses) => [...prevKeypresses, e.keyCode]);
```

This way, React will run callback function providing latest value of `keypresses` as parameter (`prevKeypresses`) and so you can update state without re-attaching event listener every time `keypresses` changes

Comment: No, I mean to keep all your code as is and modify only line where you call `setKeypresses`

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the `keypresses` array always reset it because your pointer of the `updateKeypresses` function isn't changed.
to fix it you have to add the `keypresses` state to the dependecies array of useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', updateKeypresses);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', updateKeypresses);
    };
  }, [keypresses]);
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should update your state like this:

```
  setKeypresses(prevKeypresses => [...prevKeypresses, e.keyCode]);
```

Because, when updating state based on the previous state, it's recommended to use the functional form to ensure that you are working with the most up-to-date state.